# Django iterate queryset just n number of times in templates

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

My issue is quite simple. I am using Django taggit.

I want to iterate this only 2 times. Means to display only 4 tags in templates.

```
 {% for tag in data.tags.all %}
     {{tag}}                            
 {% endfor %}
```

I have tried this, but it is not making any sense:

```
 {% for tag in data.tags.all|ljust:"2" %}
    {{tag}}                            
 {% endfor %}
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{% for tag in data.tags.all|slice:':2' %}
    {{ tag }}                            
{% endfor %}
```